# Android:webview issue

Tags: android-webview

I need to load the url something like https://m.ongein.nl in my web view and the url does not exists.So my webview will be always waiting for page finish.so need to find out if the domain does not exists then quit the web view or give error message.Is there any way to resolve the issue?
 I have check the log but i can not find the solution

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement `WebViewClient`'s [`onReceivedError`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onReceivedError%28android.webkit.WebView,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) for your `WebView` in conjunction with some `TIME_OUT`. If your `WebViewClient` Has not received the `onPageFinished` Callback till `TIME_OUT` or `onReceivedError`, whichever occurs first, then stop loading the page.